# How to correctly use the answer to a POST request as a source for audio element?

Tags: javascript, post, audio

First of all this is my first message here so I want to say thank you for all the great help provided by the community.

I'm working on a small web project where I use a PHP script as a source for an audio html 5 object.

HTML code :

```
<audio id="audioPlayer" preload="metadata"></audio>
```

(note that I set audioPlayer.preload to "metadata" to avoid useless network traffic)

Javascript code :

```
audioPlayer.src = "mp3wrapper.php" + "?filename=" + name + "&tonsofparameters";
```

PHP code for mp3wrapper.php (server side) :

```
$filename = $_GET['filename'];
$mp3content = file_get_contents($filename);
// do somme stuf with $mp3content

header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
header('Content-length: ' . strlen($mp3content));
header('Content-Disposition: filename="doesntmatter.mp3"');
header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');          
echo $mp3_content;
```

Now this works, but I find it ugly to pass tons of parameters to mp3wrapper.php through the GET method.

**Question** : How do I get the exact same result, using the POST method ?

**What I tried** : the fetch API

```
let data = new FormData()
data.append('filename',name);
...
data.append('otherparameter','othervalue');

fetch('mp3wrapper.php', {method:'POST', body:data})
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.blob();
    })
    .then(function(myBlob) {
        var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
        audioPlayer.src = objectURL;
    });
```

**Problem :** the *preload* parameter has not effect on data traffic here, the whole mp3 file is sent as soon as fetch is called (can see that in chrome inspector), which is not acceptable for me.

I've got the feeling that I need to make my own audio player implementation using the web audio API but it's getting to complicated for me.

Thanks.